# Need clarification: Yii2, MySQL Procedures, and Temporary tables

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, yii2

In my PHP Yii2 project, I am calling a MySQL Stored Procedure that creates a temporary table among other things and takes about 3-4 seconds to complete.

Does Yii2 reuse the same database connection for all users or does it create a new one, every time a user visits the website? I understand that the temporary tables are relative to a connection.

So, if I have 50+ users at the same time using the feature that calls the procedure, then is there a chance that all the procedures try to use the same temp table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary table is created for each connection. it means the table is created every time a user visits your site. But there isn't chance that calls of the procedure in different connections try to use the same temp table, because a temp table is visible only to current connection

Comment: So am I right in saying that Yii creates a new PDO connection for each user or page visit that uses a DB based model, and does not use the same connection for all the users of the site?

Comment: Yes, on default yii creates a new connection for each application run